# Fast Fourier Transform on motor vibration signal in python

Tags: python, pandas, signals, fft

I collected some data(178,432) of motor vibration signal, and the unit was g(Acceleration). The Sampling rate of signal is 25000/sec, motor speed is 1500rpm(25hz). But while I try to do the FFT using python, the picture isn't right. Can anyone help me with it?

my data : https://drive.google.com/file/d/12V8H3h6ved4lBflVxoHo2Qv5rfVZqXf0/view?usp=sharing

Here is my code:

```
import scipy.fftpack
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nor = pd.read_csv('normal.csv', header=1)

N = nor.size # data size
T = 1.0 / 25000.0 # inverse of sampling rate
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
y = nor.values
yf = np.abs(scipy.fft(y))
xf = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(nor.size, d=T)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.abs(xf), np.abs(yf))
plt.show()
```

my FFT plot:

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate what's wrong with the picture.

Comment: it is suppose to be like this kind of pictureL http://www.arduinoos.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/fft_02.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you access the [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) of a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) you get an array of arrays, or a 2D array:

```
In [23]: pd.read_csv('../Downloads/normal.csv', header=1).values
Out[23]: 
array([[ 0.006038 ],
       [ 0.0040734],
       [ 0.0031316],
       ..., 
       [-0.0103366],
       [-0.0025845],
       [ 0.0012779]])
```

And so the result of `scipy.fft(y)` is an array of `nor.size` separate 1-dimensional 1-item DFFT result arrays, in other words the original signal:

```
In [42]: scipy.fft(y)
Out[42]: 
array([[ 0.0060380+0.j],
       [ 0.0040734+0.j],
       [ 0.0031316+0.j],
       ..., 
       [-0.0103366+0.j],
       [-0.0025845+0.j],
       [ 0.0012779+0.j]])
```

You then proceeded to plot the absolute value of the original signal, against the FFT freqs. Instead you'll want to perform a single DFFT against a vector:

```
In [49]: yf = scipy.fft(nor['Channel_0  '].values)  # column/series values

In [50]: yf
Out[50]: 
array([ 1.58282430+0.j        , -3.61766030-1.86904326j,
       -0.50666930+4.24825582j, ...,  4.54241118-0.97200708j,
       -0.50666930-4.24825582j, -3.61766030+1.86904326j])

In [51]: x = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(yf.size, 1 / 25e3)

In [56]: plot(x[:x.size//2], abs(yf)[:yf.size//2])  # omit fold
Out[56]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f2f39f01cf8>]
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, because I set the frequency at 25hz, so shouldn't the tallest part appears at 25hz instead of 50 hz? Or is it because there are noises interfering the motor vibration?

Comment: I'm afraid that that is beyond my comprehension. It has been a long time since I took the relevant courses about signals, and I've no experience or education about motors. Double check that the frequency bins etc. are correct (in other words correct values passed to `fftfreq()` etc). There seems to be a rather large amplitude at 25Hz as well, so could the 50Hz spike be some resonance thing?

Comment: The spike being at double the RPM, and this being about vibration, could it be due to some back-and-forth movement? What kind of motor is that? And I've no idea if that even makes any sense...